# Rails 3 Devise Can't find controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am newbie with *Devise*.

I have installed *Devise*.
Now I have:
1) model named *User*
2) some predefined templates in */views/devise/* folder

But I have discovered than there is no any controller for user actions. When I try to send the request *http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up* my *application.html.erb* is rendered, but I expect to get a user registration form.

Could anyone help me to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [devise intro](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

**Configuring controllers**

If the customization at the views level is not enough, you can customize each controller by following these steps:

1) Create your custom controller, for example a Admins::SessionsController:

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

2) Tell the router to use this controller:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
```

3) And since we changed the controller, it won't use the "devise/sessions" views, so remember to copy "devise/sessions" to "admin/sessions".

Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in was successful or failed. Devise expects your application to call "flash[:notice]" and "flash[:alert]" as appropriate.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Alfonso, thanks for help. Your question is quite helpful. But I still have a problems with rendering a Devise registration form. I have in log: **Rendered C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.7/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (46.9ms)**. But in browser I see only my rendered application.html.erb without the registration form.

Comment: Alfonso, I am so sorry about your worry. But the solution was so much simple. I forgot to add **<%= yield %>** to application.html.erb ))